# Angular2 Impelements vs imports

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm going through the Angular2 guide, and though the keyword `implements` is used in class definitions it is not really described thoroughly in the docs.

For example, in the following:

```
export class CrisisDetailComponent implements OnInit, CanDeactivate {

  crisis: Crisis;
  editName: string;

  cancel() {
    this.editName = this.crisis.name;
    this.gotoCrises();
  }

  save() {
    this.crisis.name = this.editName;
    this.gotoCrises();
  }
}
```

`OnInit` is brought into the class by the `implements` keyword, but I've most commonly seen `OnInit` imported via `import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core'` which is then used in class definitions.

What is the utility of the `implements` keyword? And, `OnInit` is not used directly in this class definition, so why is it being brought into the class at all? Is `implements` making `OnInit` available to the `goToCrises()` method? If so, why couldn't you just inject `OnInit` into the component that defined `goToCrises()`?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> OnInit is brought into the class by the implements keyword

But you still need to have the `import` to bring `OnInit` *into the file*.

## PS:

`implements` *only brings in the type information* and not any *runtime*. You can easily remove `OnInit` and no functionality would change, its just making sure that the class follows the structure of `OnInit`

Comment: I'm not totally sure I understand. Why is ```OnInit``` being implemented then? Are we using some functionality from it? Is this class able to hook into lifecycle hooks via ```implements OnInit```?

Comment: @nikkwong - *all* classes are able to hook onto *all* lifecycle events, *regardless* of whether they implement anything, just by having methods named `ngOnWhatever`. The interfaces (which are removed at compile time), are just there to make sure we implement the hooks we say we want.

Comment: Angular checks if a class implements an interface, if it does implement it, it calls the lifecycle method. `implements OnInit` is like "yes, I fulfill the contract of OnInit". Angular then knows the class actually  has the method of ngOnInit. Especially in Dart (don't know TS reflection),  checking if a class has a method is expensive, checking `someVar is OnInit` is cheap but fulfills the same purpose here.

Comment: There is no reflection on TS interfaces. Since this is a TS question, interface has no effect on runtime